# Manipulando links com acentos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, link, acentuação

Estou capturando links de notícias publicadas num determinado site usando o seguinte código:

```
        function academia(){

            function makeNews(res){
                var soup = $(res.responseText).find('div [class~="tileImage"] h2');

                soup.each(function(e){

                    var title = $(this).find('a').text();
                    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');                              
                    var noticie = '<table class="noticias"><tr><td class="noticia_link" rowspan="3"><a href="http://www.fab.mil.br' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></td></tr></table>';

                    $('#news-list').append(noticie);
                    $('.loading-alert').hide();
                    $('.news-list-title').css('visibility','visible');

                });
            }


            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.fab.mil.br/noticias/tag/SANTOS_DUMONT',
                type: 'GET',
                success: makeNews
            });
        }


        $(function() {
            academia();
        });
```

O problema é que os links têm o título da notícia com acentos e tudo mais.

Quando carrego na página (gerada com php) onde serão listados, os símbolos aparecem trocados. Por exemplo: 
http://www.fab.mil.br/noticias/mostra/18047/TREINAMENTO---Cadetes-da-Academia-da-For%E7a-A%E9rea-realizam-instru%E7%E3o-de-salto-de-emerg%EAncia-

Dão erro 404 ao serem abertos. Experimentei charsets diferentes no php mas não resolve.

Há alguma saída simples para capturar os links exatamente como eles são?

ADIÇÃO: Esse é o código que vai na página php

```
    <div class="loading-alert">
    <h2>Buscando noticias...</h2>
    </div>
    <ul id="news-list"></ul>
```

E Esse é o código que faz o trabalho de verdade:

```
    /**
     * jQuery.ajax mid - CROSS DOMAIN AJAX 
     * ---
     * @author James Padolsey (http://james.padolsey.com)
     * @version 0.11
     * @updated 12-JAN-10
     * ---
     * Note: Read the README!
     * ---
     * @info http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
     */

     jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

     var protocol = location.protocol,
     hostname = location.hostname,
     exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
     YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test(protocol)?'s':'') + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
    query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

function isExternal(url) {
    return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
}

return function(o) {

    var url = o.url;

    if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {

        // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

        o.url = YQL;
        o.dataType = 'json';

        o.data = {
            q: query.replace(
                '{URL}',
                url + (o.data ?
                    (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                : '')
            ),
            format: 'xml'
        };

        // Since it's a JSONP request
        // complete === success
        if (!o.success && o.complete) {
            o.success = o.complete;
            delete o.complete;
        }

        o.success = (function(_success){
            return function(data) {

                if (_success) {
                    // Fake XHR callback.
                    _success.call(this, {
                        responseText: (data.results[0] || '')
                            // YQL screws with <script>s
                            // Get rid of them
                            .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                    }, 'success');
                }

            };
        })(o.success);

    }

    return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

     };

     })(jQuery.ajax);
```

Comment: Usando o Google Chrome 36 aparece-me tudo bem. Consegue partilhar print screens para melhor entender o seu problema?

Comment: Você diz que abriu esse link no Chrome e carregou a página corretamente? Pra mim aparece com o seguinte erro, tanto no chrome quanto no IE: "Ops! Parece que a sua requisição gerou um erro 500. 
 Caso o erro persista, entre em contato com um administrator. " O link certo seria: http://www.fab.mil.br/noticias/mostra/18047/TREINAMENTO---Cadetes-da-Academia-da-For%C3%A7aa-A%C3%A9rea-realizam-instru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-salto-de-emerg%C3%AAncia-

Comment: Se você simplesmente remover o *slug* do link, ele funciona corretamente: http://www.fab.mil.br/noticias/mostra/18047/

Comment: Eu vi, mas não me ocorre como fazer isso. Alguma direção que você pode me indicar em javascript ou php?

Comment: você recebe os acentos trocados ou quando você gera os links eles trocam?

Comment: Só trocam na página gerada. Este é o código dela: `<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<script src="assets/js/news-g1.js"></script>


<div id="conteudo">

<div class="lista">
<table class="noticias"><tr class="g1"><td class="noticia_link" rowspan="3"> </td></tr></table>
<div class="loading-alert"><h2>Buscando noticias...</h2></div>
  <ul id="news-list"></ul>

</div>

</div>
  
 
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>`

Comment: amigo, esse bloco de codigo nao faz absolutamente nada relativo ao problema - é HTML puro... se vc recebe os acentos corretos (áéíóú) o problema pode ser a codificação, esta usando UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode remover o *slug* por regex:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.fab.mil.br/noticias/mostra/18047/TREINAMENTO---Cadetes-da-Academia-da-For%E7a-A%E9rea-realizam-instru%E7%E3o-de-salto-de-emerg%EAncia-";
preg_match('~(.+)(\d*\/)~', $url, $semSlug);
var_dump($semSlug[1]);
?>
```

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso pondo o link automaticamente

Comment: @Roberto, o Stack Overflow em Português não é um serviço de **faça o meu código**. A minha resposta te leva para o caminho certo e não precisa de muito para adaptar o que já tem. Tente entender o Script que postou do **James Padolsey** e o adapte junto com o que postei para as suas necessidades ou **contrate um programador para fazer o serviço.**